# Error when adding a self-signed certificate in Android

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I'm trying to setup a self-signed certificate from Android using retrofit and following the instructions on this site: https://adiyatmubarak.wordpress.com/2016/01/19/adding-ssl-certificate-to-retrofit-2/

After doing it, I'm getting the following **Error:**

```
 06-17 00:36:01.574 9898-9898/com.creardigitalm.samsungconciergeargentina     
    E/checkIfS7OrS7EdgeByModel: onFailure: Hostname ec2-54-187-245-213.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com not verified:certificate:sha1/x+YzLQ11jAtlgEG6qJg8W9cqp/k=
    DN:1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#161e6c7569732e6a6172616d696c6c6f40637265617264697469616c2e636f6d,CN=54.187.245.213,OU=IT,O=Crear Digital,L=Cali,ST=Valle del Cauca,C=co
    subjectAltNames: []
    javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname ec2-54-187-245-213.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com not verified:
    certificate: sha1/x+YzLQ11jAtlgEG6qJg8W9cqp/k=
    DN:1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#161e6c7569732e6a6172616d696c6c6f40637265617264697469616c2e636f6d,CN=54.187.245.213,OU=IT,O=Crear Digital,L=Cali,ST=Valle del Cauca,C=co subjectAltNames: []
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:197)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:145)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:108)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: I think your app got this exception because of `CN=54.187.245.213`, how did you set your HostnameVerifier? Please read https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs

Answer (score 0):

You can follow Android's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) on this. Check out the sections with the titles "`Unknown certificate authority`" and "`Self-signed server certificate`".

What you will be doing is storing the self-signed certificate in your app's bundle and then use Android to trust the new self-signed certificate. Following are the steps as mentioned in their documentation.

1. Load CAs from an InputStream
2. Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
3. Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
4. Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
5. Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext

You can find the code [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html).

Comment: Yes, those are exactly the steps I am following but I still get the error.